# Can't able to build app that use inappbrowser

Tags: cordova, inappbrowser, quasar-framework

We installed a new version of cordova-plugin-inappbrowser and can't build the ios(we didn't try the android yet) version of the quasar application anymore, the error we get:
`no such file or directory: '/Plugins/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/CDVInAppBrowser.m'`
Did someone had this issue and how to solve it?

cordova-ios - 6.2.0

cordova-plugin-inappbrowser - 5.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I install `cordova-plugin-inappbrowser` version 4 and it all works, look like apache didn't update all packages at once to be complementary.